# append images horizontally command line

Tags: command-line, images, panorama

We have a bunch of tiff image files. We want to add them horizontally and create one image. Tried multiple options like Imagemagick's convert command, Irfan's view panorama command.
(actually all it does is to stich the images side by side, so its not a panorama in the proper sense but it doesn't matter)

The problem with IM's convert is it will take huge amounts of time since the tiff files are big. Issue with IrfanView panorama command is it will automatically resize the whole resultant file to the size of the first image in that list.

There are tools like FastStone and XnView which have a "Image Strip Builder" which create the panorama image neatly without taking much time. But there is no command line equivalent to FastStone GUI tool. We want to perform the same thing through command line so that it can be called from the Java application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at [Panorama Tools](http://panotools.sourceforge.net/). It includes a library, command line tools and front-end GUI for the command line tools. Source code is provided but there are also links to binaries for various platforms.